# SQL User Transactions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with multiple users that keeps track of application login date and time.

I am looking for a way to pull the last date they log on to the app 1 entry per user?

```
Column1 = userid 
Column2 = date
```

I have try multiple examples but none are working as bellow:

```
select * 
from 
    (select * 
     from ACCTRANS 
     ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) AS x 
GROUP BY 
    USERID
```

Comment: if i use the following i get the last transaction on the table only.                   SELECT * FROM ACCTRANS WHERE TIMESTAMP = (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM ACCTRANS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT UserId, MAX(TIMESTAMP) 
FROM ACCTRANS
GROUP BY UserId
```

Comment: Tom, I need to add two more columns and i get an error because they are not part of the Group? --- Column 'ACCTRANS.ENTERVALUE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.